# Dragon Mothers: Recruiting?

Tags: society, magic, fantasy-races

After many years of struggling to survive against hostile humans, even traveling into an alternate dimension with the help of a powerful wizard, the dragons have come up with a daring plan to preserve their species. Taking female humans, they will take and convert samples of their DNA into SEDNA (Spiritual Equivalent of DNA) and send them inside her body, causing the human to give birth to a dragon *in human form!*

Surely, this will bamboozle the dragonslayers, which will likely see the resulting children as powerful mages and nothing more. If they use magic to try and identify these kids as dragons, they'll find no evidence and assume they are regular people (as far as one can be *regular* with powerful magic).

However, the dragons has come across a little snag in logistics. How on Earth are they going to get female humans to agree to this? So, my question is: What is the best way for these dragons to recruit/obtain women for this purpose?

Assume humans, in general, are anti-dragon due to government propaganda, and that there are *only* two sapient species, human and dragon.

Also assume that dragonslayers, in order to protect their women from dragons in human form, set up a sort of '9-1-1 network' that allows a woman to alert the dragonslayers if she has a dragon problem, causing a squad of dragonslayers to teleport in and deal with the dragon.

This network is powered by a special rune, tattooed on during childhood, that allows females to telepathically 'call 9-1-1', so to speak. Since it's *mental*, it's just about impossible to stop, and so the dragons really want to avoid conflict and gain consent.

Comment: This is more in the Slavonic or Russian tradition, with Dragons romancing humans. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zmei_(Russian) or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavic_dragon The dragons shape-change into human form, typically. So you need some charming dragon heroes.

Comment: Not really; it's more like using a sperm bank, no romance needs be involved.

Comment: It's not clear how a "dragon in human form", which grows up among humans, has (partially) human DNA, is socialized as a human, and will likely think of itself as a (powerful) human, benefits the dragons.

Comment: Simply put, survival. You see, dragonslayers have no qualms about slating dragons, but humans that seem to have no connection to them? Yeah, not likely a dragonslayer would kill them.

Comment: Yes, but if you want to convince human women to have draconic children, you need to woo them. The kids were either monstrous OR great heroes, so play up the heroic example. Marketing!

Comment: Speaking of marketing, couldn't you just _pay_ them to do that?

Comment: Even with humans, consent is not always an issue. In legends and mythology, dragons are often very powerful, very magical, and very arrogant. I see no problem with them using their magic to coerce human women.

Comment: Very insightful, but here's your problem; what's to stop the women from calling the dragonslayers?

Comment: OK, I have to remind you that there is all sorts of humans. Serial killers are apparently quite popular with (some) ladies. I'm pretty sure there are women who would be more than thrilled by the prospect of having a draconic child.

Comment: Hold up, why on Earth would women find a _serial killer_attractive? Doesn't that severely decrease their prospects of survival?

Comment: @Alendyias unfortunately, I've not looked into any studies into the behaviour. Mostly because I fear that I won't like the information I get from them. However, convicted male serial killers apparently get a lot of fan mail from women.

Comment: It's okay, I probably shouldn't have asked.

Comment: Is a dragon in human form, who thinks itself a human, really continuing the survival of dragons?

Comment: Good question, Lio. My next question will be about getting these dragon-born children into the fold.

Answer (score 2):

### Fertility Issues

To add onto the Alliance/Agreement category, they are powerful magicians.  If marketed properly, this could be put forth as a solution for couples that are having issues in conception.  This can, of course come from both sides of the relationship.

The powerful magics that are transmuting the DNA from dragon to human might also have the potential to break through whatever infertility that a couple is having, and allow them to have a child.  Sure it's a draconic child, but unmentioned is how much of a role the draconic donor will have in the child's life.

Any odd appearances of the child, such as an unusual hair or eye colour or  is attributed to them being strong in the magical arts and not a sign of one spouse cheating on the other.

#### Unspeakable Love

All right, not unspeakable *now*, but in this world?  Who knows.  But it is fair to say that a lesbian couple that desires both children and secrecy might resort to this in order to have the child that they want.  Doubly so if one of the ladies is posing as a guy to hide their relationship further.

Now this is, obviously, dependent on the world and its social structures and norms, but it is something that could be.  It might be that a lady in this sort of relationship might actually look for these dragons or their envoys to solve their childbearing issues.

If homosexual relationships are not stigmatized, then a couple might still seek the dragons or their envoys out so as not to make things awkward in their town of residence.

#### Conclusion

In conclusion, women that potentially can't have children for whatever reason put dealing with dragons as an acceptable cost of having the child they always wanted.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way for these dragons to recruit/obtain women for this purpose?

Assuming the conception of the baby dragon is a strictly biological/magical process which does not require soul bonding or anything like that, there are many approach to this problem.

**Anonymity**
The powerful wizard who is helping the dragons invite women to a secret experiment, he tell them he is trying to create a babe born of magic itself, rather than having a biological father and mother. This will help justifying why the children are so powerful, but require the dragons to receive help from within the human realm.

**Shapeshifting**
Since the dragons in human form will be powerful wizards, I assume the dragons may have some magic of their own (apart from being fire breathing flying lizards). If they can shape shift, they can impregnate the girls in disguise, either as a human man or in the greek god way. This may involve a actual relationship with the women or not. This come with the risk of being tracked by dragon slayers and the possibility that they can trace the children as not human more easily.

**Kidnaping**
Since they are dragons, kidnaping princesses is the natural solution for this problem. Since they are of politically important families, dragon slayers suspecting the children are dragons would cause internal conflict, which may reduce their overall support. Also, having dragons born in major families may grant them some power to stop they dragon hunting in one generation or two.

**Alliance/Agreement**
Since dragons probably are powerful being, there should be some faction among humans who are trying to use them, even if in a discreet manner. Like the leader of a rebel group agree to bear the child if the dragon attacks a fortress, making her enemies move troops in order to deal with him.

Comment: This is a great answer, I love these ideas! There's even an option for recruitment! However, kidnapping princesses will lead to A) suspicion (which the dragons want to avoid) and B) be too obvious. They _want_ to be as secretive as possible.

Comment: Also, what do you think of a cult as a recruitment method?

Comment: @Alendyias  a cult would work great, but I don't know enough about these dragons to know if they could pull that off. And the princesses might be capture as hostages in a "despaired attempt to end the senseless slaughter of their kind", if the princess is already married and in fertile age, there will not be much questions about why the are pregnant. Ideally they should combine methods to avoid pattern recognition

Comment: Good point, thank you!