# Dragons Rising: Subverting the Dragonslayers

Tags: society, fantasy-races

After their success with the Dragon Mother and Dragonborn Repatriation projects, ( see [Dragon Mothers: Recruiting?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/192834/dragon-mothers-recruiting) and [Dragon Children: Bringing Them Into The Fold?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/192936/dragon-children-bringing-them-into-the-fold) if you're curious), the dragons have hit a *little* setback.

You see, the entire plan was for the Dragonborn (literally, dragons born in human form) to infiltrate and take over the fiercely anti-dragon human realm. However, the dragons haven't accounted for the dragonslayers. These are altered humans (or descendants of altered humans) who have been made superhuman, physically and magically (they are powerful mages) and are literally wired to be fiercely anti-dragon; if it wasn't for the dragon's escape into an alternate world, they would have driven them to extinction.

If the Dragonborn are to take over and introduce pro-dragon legislature, the Dragonslayers would do a *lot* more than just rebel. They'd do everything in their power to sabotage and eliminate the Dragonborn leadership, so they need to be dealt with. So their question is: **What is the best way to subvert the dragonslayers?**

If you need more information:

1. The dragons want to totally reverse the dragonslayer's anti-dragon drive, making them pro-dragon. Instead of dragon *slayers*, they'd be dragon defenders. Barring that, they want to overcome the dragonslayers aforementioned anti-dragon drive through indoctrination, the 25th frame effect (or other subliminal stimuli), hypnosis, or by having their alarm clocks deliver messages to their subconscious while they're sleeping (Fred....Fred.....you know you aren't a true dragonslayer....your calling is of a different sort.....loyalty to the dragons.....lies deep within....you will never be truly.....happy....until you give in). Put whatever methods you believe are best in your answer.
2. If you don't believe the dragonslayers *can* be subverted, explain *why* and put how best to eliminate them instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based off that sort of manipulative power your dragon born seem to have, there's a better solution:

Turn other factions within the world against the dragon slayers, using your dragon born. You can simultaneously stop attacking those groups. This will make the Dragon Slayers suspect that those people are dragon worshipers, and so they'll start to focus their energies attacking what they perceive as a dragon cult.

You can then use this as propaganda to prove the dragon slayers are crazy inquisitors or such, while also trying to encourage them into being crazy inquisitors. So, you can disable them and many human nations as a threat, through infighting.

Then, they might be more willing to reconsider their place in the world, and their stance on dragons, after a couple of wars with humans. Most likely, they'd only agree to a truce with dragons so that they can reestablish their organization's power and influence.

### Recruiting the Dragon Slayers

If you really want to get some dragon slayers on your side... the emphasis is on some. Create a division within their faction, probably using these wars I mentioned as a source for that division. You might start just by having a dragon-neutral party you support from the shadows, and then later you can split that into a dragon-sympathetic party. As you divide and weaken the dragon slayers, you will have a better chance of recruiting them to your cause.

That does mean you'll get a much weaker organization out of it, but if you can just breed more of them... then it's a good long term plan to get some superhuman pets you can raise.

Comment: I never even thought out of this, but it would work great! Thank you!

Comment: @Alendyias Glad it was useful. Had thought something was wrong with my answer, and that was why no one voted on it.

Comment: I don't know why the others didn't, but for me,  that's just because I'm new and often forget to upvote.